# How is an overthrow represented on the wagonwheel?

Tags: cricket, statistics

The "wagonwheel" is a diagram used to show where a batsman's shots were played, colourcoded for the number of runs scored from that shot.

An overthrow occurs when a fielding player attempts to return the ball to the stumps, either directly or indirectly, but through some error causes the ball to be sent to another area of the field instead.

Suppose a batsman plays a shot to one side of the field, scoring runs from it. An overthrow to the other side then allows additional runs.

**How would this shot and overthrow be represented on the wagonwheel? How are the runs coded?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is two wagon wheel from [ESPN Cricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/249223.html) showing overthrow.

What I did was to look for overthrow causing 7 runs in an ashes 06/07 Adelaide test Australia 2nd inning by Michael Clarke [Link to Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqswGyXGzlg) and search the same match in cricinfo for wagon wheel.

Michael Clarke wagon wheel:
[image: Overthrow in wagon wheel]

The white line in wagon wheel is overthrow 7 runs because Clarke has scored only 10 runs against Flintoff. Among which 1sx1 and 2sx1 and no 4s or 6s.

Andrew Flintoff wagon wheel:
[image: flintoff wagon wheel]

Which clearly shows 7 runs in wagon wheel as no fours or six have been scored against him by **Clarke**.

Answer (score -3):

It would be represented as the first shot the batsmen has played even though the throw has been missed and u get runs through it. This is because the first shot triggered the whole event this makes the wagon wheel to show that the runs have been scored by the batsmen with the first shot. This is my personal view

Comment: Is this from a document that states how an organiser will actually record an overthrow, or just what you think should happen? Please refer to appropriate and credible sources.